# Create a True/False output column in Power BI that evaluates a column with text strings

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I want to get a True/False Output column that evaluates another column of text strings

```
Table

    Item        Notes                   Carried
    1           Bob was able to..       Y
    2           Amy was not....         N
    3           This is Bob.....        N
```

In this example I want a way to know if I can evaluate the Notes column for specific text by row and have a column of True/False, for the example is there a way to evaluate for occurrence of "Bob"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Containsstring, adding a new column:

```
Carried = if(CONTAINSSTRING(Table[Notes], "Bob"), "Y", "N")
```

If you want to pass in more than one value, you can go with:

```
Carried = if(CONTAINSSTRING(Table[Notes], "Bob") || CONTAINSSTRING(Table[Notes], "Amy"), "Y", "N")
```

Comment: is there a way to add 'amy' and still have same result? Just in case, just want to know if multiple values could be passed in

Comment: You can use an or `||` in your condition if you just have another one or few values.

Comment: i used AND but how is | | used?